# Error during RTSP streaming using gstreamer on the jetson nano

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

Im working on this project :

https://www.hackster.io/jonmendenhall/jetson-nano-search-and-rescue-ai-uav-9ca547

At some point I will need to mount my camera (waveshare ; IMX219-77IR) on top of the drone and I would like to use vlc on Windows or Linux outside of nomachine (because I have installed nomachine server on the nano and the client on windows and because it will run in headless mode),to display what the camera sees when the drone is flying. For this reason I’m trying to configure a gstreamer with RTSP to start a streaming server on the Ubuntu 18.04 that I have installed on the jetson nano.

Below u can see what are the commands that I have issued :

```
$ ./test-launch "videotestsrc ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96"
```

And on the same Jetson Nano, I opened another console where I ran this pipeline to decode the RTSP stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test ! nvoverlaysink
```

I see this picture :

[image]

The picture is from videotestsrc plugin. I would like to replace videotestsrc with my video source,but I don't know how to do that.

I tried these combinations,but none of them worked :

```
./test-launch "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96"

./test-launch "device=/dev/video0 ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96"
```

but the error is still the same :

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source: Could not read from resource.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(5917): gst_rtsp_src_receive_response (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Could not receive message. (Timeout while waiting for server response)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

but why ? I know for sure that my camera (model waveshare ; IMX219-77IR) created a device called /dev/video0 and I know for sure that it works,because this command is able to show my face on the screen :

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3280, height=2464, format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)20/1' ! nvoverlaysink -e
```

Comment: Also having the same problem. Did you solved yours?

Comment: try this : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tNWR8vwmkj/